# How do I solve this complex equation with $z$ and its conjugate?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

While I’ve been solving complex equations pretty fine, this exercise in my book made me stuck. How do I solve this?

$$z + i\overline{z}^2 + 2i = 0$$

Thanks a lot for the answers! I’ve tried to turn them in polar and exponential forms, mind this is calculus 1 and we’re just using basic stuff to solve this, like the quadratic formula, but no derivatives (if there is even such thing in complexes).

Comment: Assume that $z=x+iy$ and equate both the real and imaginary parts of the equation to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f=z+\bar z^2i+2i=0$, then $$f+\bar f=(z+\bar z)+i(\bar z^2-z^2)=(z+\bar z)(1+i(\bar z-z))=0$$

We have two possible cases:

1. $\bar z=-z$. Thus $\mathfrak R(z)=0$, and we have the quadratic $$z^2-iz+2=(z+i)(z-2i)=0$$
2. $\bar z-z=i$. We then get the quadratic $$i(z+i)^2+z+2i=-i((iz)^2-iz-1)=-i(z-i\phi)(z+i\phi)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$z = x+yi$

So the equation becomes $x + yi + i(x^2 - y^2 + 2xyi) + 2i = x-2xy+(x^2 - y^2 + y + 2)i = 0$

$$\begin{cases} x(1+2y) =0 \\ x^2 - y^2 + y + 2 = 0\end{cases}$$

Consider $x = 0$:
$$y^2-y-2=(y-2)(y+1)=0 \Rightarrow z = 2i \text{ or } -i$$

Consider $1+2y = 0$:
$$y=-\frac12 \Rightarrow x=i\sqrt{\frac54} \notin \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \text{ No solutions with } \Im{z} = -\frac12$$